# Cycling webpage screensaver in AutoIT breaking on local filepath

Tags: hyperlink, autoit, screensaver

I am trying to create a sort of pseudo-screensaver in AutoIT. I currently have it detecting the idle time, opening IE, and navigating to a page. I have it randomly choosing a random number and going to a page using a case statement. It cycles through live webpages and local html pages on my machine that have hyperlinks embedded.

But, for some reason when it reaches a local filepath that I am using to display a custom HTML webpage running on the local machine, the code does not continue. It will not navigate to another page. It is changing the case, but not navigating to what's set in the case. It's almost like once it gets to the local filepath, it won't change from it.

Any ideas?

```
#include <Timers.au3>
#include <IE.au3>

$oIE = _IECreate("http://www.google.com/")
$InactivityTrigger = 5*1000
$PID = 0

Sleep(3*1000)
Send("{F11}")

While True
   $InactiveFor = _Timer_GetIdleTime()

  If $InactiveFor >= $InactivityTrigger And Not $PID Then
  Switch Random(0, 5, 1)
     Case 0
        $PID = _IENavigate($oIE, "https://www.google.com")
        Send("{0}")
     Case 1
        $PID = _IENavigate($oIE, "https://www.yahoo.com")
        Send("{2}")
     Case 2
        $PID = _IENavigate($oIE, "https://www.bing.com")
        Send("{3}")
     Case 3
        $PID = _IENavigate($oIE, "C:\Users\test.html")
        Send("{4}")
     Case 4
        $PID = _IENavigate($oIE, "C:\Users\test2.html")
        Send("{5}")
     Case 5
        $PID = _IENavigate($oIE, "C:\Users\test3.html")
        Send("{6}")
  EndSwitch

  ConsoleWrite("started" & @CRLF)

  ElseIf $InactiveFor < $InactivityTrigger And $PID Then
  ProcessClose($PID)
  $PID = 0
  ConsoleWrite("stopped" & @CRLF)

EndIf

Wend
```

Comment: It's unclera, what you meand by `C:\Users\*IMAGE`. Do you use it as wildcard? Or is it actual filename? Or maybe this is a placeholder used in public question, while actual script works with different string... I tried using your script by replacing this string with `C:\Temp\sample.html` or `C:\Temp\pict.png` and it worked OK. Script displays both local images/pages and internet pages and doesn't stuck anywhere.

Comment: Yes sorry, I have updated the code with what I meant. It should have been a file path to an html page that I created. The html page is just a picture. It cycles fine for the live html pages and will cycle to the local html pages, but will not cycle from the html page to anything else. For example if it goes through link 1, 2, 3, and hits link 4 (the local html file), it will not move to the next local html file.

Comment: As already mentioned, script doesn't get stuck on local html file for me, but moves forward as expected. I used the following page for tests: `<body>HELLO, WORLD!</body>`. You might want to add debug output before and/or after each line of code, so you can determine exact step causing script to hang.